# Vue js: how to load a css animation only on the first page load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In the Home Page component, I've a `<div>` element with an animation, like this:

```
<div class="square">
   //content
</div>
```

and in the CSS:

```
.square
height: 200px
width: 200px
margin: 0 auto
z-index: 0
position: absolute
top: 38vh
left: 43vw
margin-left:auto
margin-right:auto
animation-name: stretch
animation-duration: 0.3s
animation-timing-function: ease-out
animation-delay: 0
animation-direction: alternate
animation-fill-mode: forwards
animation-play-state: running

@keyframes stretch
from
  transform: scale (1)
to
  transform: scale(1.8)
```

It is a simple square that grows, with some other `<div>` elements inside.

Now, I would like to play the animation only on initial login and opening of app, not each time the view appears (like is working now).

Could you help me? Please, don't take anything for granted, because I am a beginner. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

its simple. create a flag in the data of the vue property. you can call it `animate`. add a function that will turn it off after the login, somthing like:

```
data:{
   animate:true
   },
methods:{
   turnOffAnimate:{
      this.animate=false;
   }
}
```

call this.turnOffAnimate when you want to turn off your animation. now, in your html div, bind the class in this way:

```
<div :class="{square : animate}">
   //content
</div>
```

this condition means that your div will own `square` class only while `animate` flag is true. you can read more about [class binding in vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).